# script check all groups a user is part of in bash

Tags: bash

I want to write a shell script checking all the groups a user is part of and for each one display `<username> is part of the group <group>`. I did the script but it doesnt show me the users' names. Here is my script:

```
GroupsOfUser(){
    for i in $(groups)  ; do  
        echo "$i" "is part of" "$()"
    done 
}
GroupsOfUser '/etc/group/passwd'
```

What command should I add to the script so it shows me the user names of all the groups?

I am all new in programming and have been trying to find a solution for two days already.

Comment: When I execute the command it shows that the name of groups , but I also need it to show the username of the group

Comment: What's `/etc/group/passwd` supposed to do here? That's not a valid file on any standard system, and your function doesn't examine any file names anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system variable `$USER` contais the account name of the current user. Maybe also look at the `id` command.

```
for i in $(groups); do  
    echo "$USER is part of$i"
done
```

or more succinctly

```
printf "$USER is part of %s\n" $(groups)
```

The `groups` command alone is generally more useful; Unix utilities tend to print only the information you actually need, which makes it easier to use them to build more complex scripts (though there are common exceptions, like `ps` and `df`, and hence thousands of scripts which have to reinvent parsers for their output).

Comment: I added the systeme variable $USER and now when i execute i think it worked because it shows me the username so the results when i execute are   becode@lpt-6h5g4s ~/exercice3 % ./exercice5a.sh
becode is part of becode
adm is part of becode
cdrom is part of becode
sudo is part of becode
dip is part of becode

Comment: You seem to have the output in the wrong order (in your question, too); the usual English idiom would be _"user_ is part of _group"_ or maybe _"group_ includes _user"_ if you want to keep them in this order.

Comment: Yes I am going to fix that in the right context . Thank you so much for help